# PyQt - showing countdown timer

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer, pyqt

I am trying to create a program, using PyQt, which currently consists of a stacked widget of 4 pages. A timer has been implemented, and after 3 seconds the page the user is currently on switches to the next page. I am currently trying to add a timer which shows the user how much time on that page they have left (ideally in seconds). However, I have no idea how to connect the timer to a counter, and have not been able to find anything which would be helpful.

Here is the current code, which is basically just the timer:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from StackedWidget import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)


window = QMainWindow()


ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(window)


def NextTimer():
   ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex((ui.stackedWidget.currentIndex() + 1))


myTimer = QTimer()
myTimer.timeout.connect(NextTimer)
myTimer.start(3000)
```

I am trying to connect the timer to a counter of the class QLCDNumber,labelled Counter. At the current point there is no code which involves this counter, it just exists.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: create minimal working example with `QLCDNumber` so everyone could test it and create solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working example in PyQt5 of how you can implement the functionality you described:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

DURATION_INT = 3


class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        self.widget_counter_int = 0

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(vbox)

        self.pages_qsw = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        vbox.addWidget(self.pages_qsw)
        self.time_passed_qll = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        vbox.addWidget(self.time_passed_qll)

        self.widget_one = QtWidgets.QLabel("This is widget one")
        self.pages_qsw.addWidget(self.widget_one)
        self.widget_two = QtWidgets.QLabel("This is widget two")
        self.pages_qsw.addWidget(self.widget_two)
        self.widget_three = QtWidgets.QLabel("This is widget three")
        self.pages_qsw.addWidget(self.widget_three)
        self.widget_four = QtWidgets.QLabel("This is widget four")
        self.pages_qsw.addWidget(self.widget_four)

        self.timer_start()
        self.update_gui()

    def timer_start(self):
        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT

        self.my_qtimer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.my_qtimer.timeout.connect(self.timer_timeout)
        self.my_qtimer.start(1000)

        self.update_gui()

    def timer_timeout(self):
        self.time_left_int -= 1

        if self.time_left_int == 0:
            self.widget_counter_int = (self.widget_counter_int + 1) % 4
            self.pages_qsw.setCurrentIndex(self.widget_counter_int)
            self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT

        self.update_gui()

    def update_gui(self):
        self.time_passed_qll.setText(str(self.time_left_int))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = MyMainWindow()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: hey @sunyata your code helped me indeed. but I don't figure out how to run this in a separate window of my application.. I already have a "main window" that gets opened initially, when clicking a button, I'd like the timer window to show up.. do I need two different classes? I can't run two separate applications, so it must be in one..

Comment: @sonja Hi, i'm glad this helped you! For your situation i'd maybe inherit from a QDialog to get a new window. (You'll need to change the layout code slightly though, there isn't any "setCentralWidget" function in QDialog). If you want more help please feel free to contact me on gitter here: https://gitter.im/SunyataZero