# Simple python GUI for raspberry pi development

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, raspberry-pi, pyqt5

I need some help getting my gui to function how I intend to. So for my GUI I need two push buttons and a timer. The timer counts down on the press of start/pause, then pauses when pressed again. The other button reset should be easy as just resetting the Qtimer.

I tried to use qtdesigner to confiure the layout of my gui and while that worked, I cannot seem to add the timer in/vice versa. (it just will not show based on which one is located higher up on the .py file). For the timer I've been messing around with a modified version of the answer in this question [PyQt - showing countdown timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994187/pyqt-showing-countdown-timer?rq=1). Any assistance on helping me get a countdown timer working with button interfacing would be very helpful.

I made some changes to my code adding fixing my button slots I still cannot get the timer to display i get the error 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'setCentralWidget' which i cannot fix for the life of me. Please someone help me get the timer just on the gui I can configure where it goes latter.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
#import pymongo
#import socket
#import json
#from time import sleep

DURATION_INT = 300
state = "stopped"
#connection = pymongo.MongoClient(host='192.168.4.2', port=27017)
#db = connection.restdb

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        global state
        super().__init__()
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(648, 561)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 460, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 110, 231, 101))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 270, 61, 51))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 270, 21, 51))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 270, 61, 51))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 460, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_pause)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.reset)
 ######################################################       
        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        self.widget_counter_int = 0

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(vbox)

        self.pages_qsw = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
        vbox.addWidget(self.pages_qsw)
        self.time_passed_qll = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        vbox.addWidget(self.time_passed_qll)

        self.widget_one = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.pages_qsw.addWidget(self.widget_one)
        self.timer_start()
        self.update_gui()
#####################################################
    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Reset"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Start/Pause"))

    def timer_start(self):
        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        self.my_qtimer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.my_qtimer.timeout.connect(self.timer_timeout)
        self.my_qtimer.start(1000)
        self.update_gui()

    def timer_timeout(self):
        self.time_left_int -= 1

        if  self.time_left_int == -1:
            self.widget_counter_int = (self.widget_counter_int + 1) % 4
            self.pages_qsw.setCurrentIndex(self.widget_counter_int)
            self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT

        self.update_gui()

    def update_gui(self):
        self.time_passed_qll.setText(str(self.time_left_int))    

    def start_pause(self):
        global state
        if (state == "stopped" or state == "paused"):
            state = "running"
            print(state)
            #for g in gameData.find():
            #    gameData.update({'_id' : g['_id']}, {'state': state})

        elif (state == "running"):
            state = "paused"
            print(state)
            #for g in gameData.find():
            #    gameData.update({'_id' : g['_id']}, {'state': state})

    def reset(self):
        global state
        state = "stopped"
        print(state)
        #for g in gameData.find():
        #    gameData.update({'_id' : g['_id']}, {'state': state})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Should i edit out the first two sentences then?

Comment: I added in code and removed the first two sentences

Comment: I see the buttons, but where do you want to show the time?

Comment: I want then timer to show where the top line edit is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: you don't seem to fully grasp the GUI Object tree (which QWidget items are connected to which QWidget/layout parent)

Change

```
    Form.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
```

to

```
    self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
```

will show the form, and the label with the countdown timer is located in the lower left corner. It does not react to the buttons because the QVBoxLayout with the label and the widget_one is on top , but at least it counts down.

You can use the following statements to add a background color to a QWidget (or subclass):

```
    pal = QtGui.QPalette()
    pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtCore.Qt.red)
    self.widget_one.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```

You'll see that the widgets that you positioned manually are then hidden behind a red rectangle. This also means that the *widget_one* will capture all mouse events and you can't click anything.

I would suggest that you don't mix setLayout() and setCentralWidget(), as this will lead to (sometimes non-obvious) issues with mouse and keyboard events.

In conclusion, I presume you want to show something like this (I've left the QStackedWidget in, as I assume you want to use it later on)?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#import pymongo
#import socket
#import json
#from time import sleep

DURATION_INT = 300
state = "stopped"
#connection = pymongo.MongoClient(host='192.168.4.2', port=27017)
#db = connection.restdb

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        global state
        super().__init__()
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(648, 561)

 ######################################################       
        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        self.widget_counter_int = 0

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        Form.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(vbox)

        self.time_passed_qll = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        vbox.addWidget(self.time_passed_qll)
        self.time_passed_qll.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.time_passed_qll.setFrameStyle(QtWidgets.QFrame.Panel | QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken);
        self.time_passed_qll.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.RichText) # to be able to use html tags for color!
        self.pages_qsw = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()


        vbox.addWidget(self.pages_qsw)

        self.widget_one = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        #pal = QtGui.QPalette()
        #pal.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtCore.Qt.red)
        #self.widget_one.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        #self.widget_one.setPalette(pal)

        self.pages_qsw.addWidget(self.widget_one)

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget_one)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 460, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget_one)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 110, 231, 101))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget_one)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 270, 61, 51))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.widget_one)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 270, 21, 51))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget_one)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 270, 61, 51))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget_one)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 460, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_pause)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.reset)        

        self.timer_start()
        self.update_gui()
#####################################################
    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Reset"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Start/Pause"))

    def timer_start(self):
        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        self.my_qtimer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.my_qtimer.timeout.connect(self.timer_timeout)
        self.my_qtimer.start(1000)
        self.update_gui()

    def timer_timeout(self):
        global state
        if state == "running":
            self.time_left_int -= 1

        if  self.time_left_int == -1:
            self.widget_counter_int = (self.widget_counter_int + 1) % 4
            self.pages_qsw.setCurrentIndex(self.widget_counter_int)
            self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT

        self.update_gui()

    def update_gui(self):
        self.time_passed_qll.setText('<p style="color:green;font-size:24px">{}</p>'.format(self.time_left_int))    
        self.lineEdit.setText(str(self.time_left_int))

    def start_pause(self):
        global state
        if (state == "stopped" or state == "paused"):
            state = "running"
            print(state)
            #for g in gameData.find():
            #    gameData.update({'_id' : g['_id']}, {'state': state})

        elif (state == "running"):
            state = "paused"
            print(state)
            #for g in gameData.find():
            #    gameData.update({'_id' : g['_id']}, {'state': state})

    def reset(self):
        global state
        self.time_left_int = DURATION_INT
        state = "stopped"
        print(state)
        #for g in gameData.find():
        #    gameData.update({'_id' : g['_id']}, {'state': state})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This makes so much more sense and has helped me understand pyqt more thank you, by any chance however would you know how to get the timer to display the minutes then the seconds like 5:00.

Comment: If the answer answers your question, please mark it as such.

Comment: The timing formatting is quite unrelated to this question, but rather easy to achieve: `mins, sec = t // 60, t % 60` and then change the .format line to something like `'{0} : {1}'.format(mins, sec)` but with the appropriate html around it to show these numbers the way you want.